# zf2&zfc2 and routing

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to create admin panel using ZfcAdmin module. I want to create routing, to manage users. Here is it:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUserController',
            ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'admin-user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),

        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'zfcadmin' => array(
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'user' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/user',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser',
                                    'action'     => 'index',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'child_routes' =>array(
                                'edit' => array(
                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/edit/:user_id',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'AdminUser\Controller\AdminUser',
                                            'action'     => 'edit',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I based on info from zfcadmin github page: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin. I just copy and paste the example, and change to fix my needs. However, I recieve a error message:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Part route may not terminate'"

What's wrong?

EDIT:
I request: `/admin/user` and it's ok, but when I want to receive URL like: `/admin/user/edit/1` I always get `/admin/user` I create the link this way:

`<?php $this->url('zfcadmin/user/edit', array(
                    'action'  => 'edit',
                    'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                )) ?>`

Comment: Which uri are you requesting?

Comment: I think it is `'may_terminate' => true,` before the 2nd `child_routes`

Comment: I added `'may_terminate' => true,`, requested /admin/user and displaying ok, but `<?php $this->url('zfcadmin/user/edit', array(
     'action'  => 'edit',
     'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
    ))` returns /admin/user uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creating URL incorrectly. Please create the link like this.

```
<?php $this->url('zfcadmin/user/edit', array( 'user_id' => $user['user_id'], ) ?>
```